# Kivy ScrollView too many Children issue

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, scrollview

I'm getting an error when trying to run my kivy script that :

```
Exception: ScrollView accept only one widget
```

This is where i define my ScrollView Class:

```
class UsersList(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UsersList, self).__init__(**kwargs, scroll_timeout=250)
        elo: Elo = App.get_running_app().eloSystem

        # Create a BoxLayout
        self.all_buttons = []

        # self.all_buttons = [UserButton(
        #     text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40) for i in range(30)]

        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint_y=None)

        WarningPopup(f"{elo.get_rowers()}")

        # Make the height of the layout such that it can scroll
        self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter('height'))

        # Create buttons and add them to the layout
        for button in self.all_buttons:
            self.layout.add_widget(button)

        # Add the layout to the ScrollView
        self.add_widget(self.layout)
```

I'm wondering why I keep getting this error, only started happening when I updated kivy and tried installing my project with pyinstaller. before it was working fine